# Flow error in promise then function

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I'm using flow 0.59.0

After declaration of the function that returns `fetch` result I try to call `then` but flow shows me an error

`` [flow] type parameter `U` of call of method `then` (Missing annotation) ``

the code

```js
type FetchOptions = {
  url: URL,
  body?: Body,
  method: Method,
  json: boolean
}

const publicFetch = (args: FetchOptions) => {
  const options = {
    ...defaultFetchOptions,
    ...args
  }
  const { url, method, body, json } = options
  const headers: Headers = createHeaders(json)
  const request: Request = createRequest(headers, url, method, body)
  return fetch(request)
}
const publicFetchJSON = (args: FetchOptions) => 
  // HERE IS AN ERROR mentioned before
  publicFetch(args).then(response => response.json())
```

What does flow expect from me?

Comment: I'll guess that it wants to know the type of `response`/the return type of `publicFetch`/the return type of `fetch(request)`

Comment: @Bergi I've added `const response: Response = await fetch(request); return response` to the end of `publicFetch` but flow still throws an error

Comment: screenshot from VS Code https://screencast.com/t/Afhb9qQeyT

Comment: you are using `promise` value in `publicFetchJSON`. That's why, you don't need to `await` on `fetch` in `publicFetch` function, specify `Promise<Response>` as the return type of `publicFetch`. You can also use `Promise<any>` as return type for `publicFetchJSON`, if you are using [this](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/bom.js#L972) for type annotation of `Response`

Comment: @SALEH I've tried, it doesn't help